# How do I render a Dundas bar chart from most to least?

Tags: mschart, dundas

How does one order the bar chart series to render from most to least? Ordering the data before binding does not seem to help.

[image: bar chart that that is rendering least to most]

My code:

```
chart.Series.Add("port");
chart.Series["port"].Type = SeriesChartType.Bar;
chart.Series["port"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";
chart.Series["port"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";
chart.Series["port"].ShowLabelAsValue = true;
chart.Series["port"].Points.DataBind(myData, "Key", "Value", "Label=Value{p2}");
chart.Series["port"].BorderStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
chart.Series["port"].BorderColor = Color.White;
chart.Series["port"].BorderWidth = 1;
chart.Series["port"].ShowLabelAsValue = true;
chart.Series["port"].Font = myfont;

chart.ChartAreas.Add("Default");
chart.ChartAreas["Default"].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
foreach (var axis in chart.ChartAreas["Default"].Axes)
{
    axis.LabelStyle.Font = myfont;
    axis.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
}
chart.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "p0";
```

Comment: Do you just want to reverse the order of what you have right now?

Comment: @drachenstein Yes. So in the chart image above, one will see Canada, United States and European Union, in that order from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call Sort() on the series, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455394.aspx. So to sort the points from most to least you'd do

```
chart.Series["port"].Sort(PointSortOrder.Descending);
```

There are two other sort methods incase you need to sort by something other than the point value.

Comment: This call needs to be made AFTER calling the DataBind method. If called before, the sort will not work.